# How to Inherit from a base datamodule in Delphi7

Tags: delphi, inheritance, encapsulation

I created a base datamodule as such:

```
unit dmi_Generic;
...
type
  TDMGenericClass = class of TdmiGeneric;

  TdmiGeneric = class(TDataModule)
private
  ReferencedForms: FormIDTypes;
public
  class procedure CloseDM(FormName: string; dm: TdmiGeneric);
  class function OpenDM(FormName: string; dm: TdmiGeneric; const dmClass:
                        TDMGenericClass): TdmiGeneric;
end;
...
class function TdmiGeneric.OpenDM(FormName: string; dm: TdmiGeneric; const
                dmClass: TDMGenericClass):
                TdmiGeneric;
var
    FormID: Integer;
begin
    FormID := GetFormID(FormName);
    if dm = nil then
        dm := dmClass.Create(nil);   //trouble is probably born here
    with dm do
        if not (FormID in ReferencedForms) then
            ReferencedForms := ReferencedForms + [FormID];
    Result := dm;
end;
...
```

I intended to inherit other datamodules from dmi_generic, so, in another unit...

**Edit1**

```
uses
    dmi_Generic;
...
type
  TdmUserSecurity = class(TdmiGeneric)
... 
var
  dmUserSecurity: TdmUserSecurity;
```

and in my main form...

```
uses
  UserSecurityDM;
  ...
procedure TfmMain.actUserManagerExecute(Sender: TObject);
begin
  dmUserSecurity := TdmUserSecurity.OpenDM(Self.Name,dmUserSecurity,TdmUserSecurity);
  //some code
  TdmUserSecurity.CloseDM(Self.Name,dmUserSecurity);
end;
```

**Edit2:**
...which gives compile error "Incompatible type. 'TdmUserSecurity' and 'TdmiGeneric'"

How do I fix this, properly? Do I typecast the return value at the main form, or is there something I should change at the dmi_generic unit? TIA

Comment: Obvious first question: What is TdmiGeneric1?

Comment: I intend to create datamodules to inherit from a base type, which has a class method to track references (count) to it. The reference is used to decide when to destroy the dm, if there are no more references to it.

Comment: You should be using automatic reference-counted interfaces for that purpose, not manually tracking the references yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`OpenDM()` returns a `TdmiGeneric` pointer.  But `dmUserSecurity` is not declared as `TdmiGeneric`, so you will get an error on this assignment:

```
dmUserSecurity := TdmUserSecurity.OpenDM(...);
```

You would need a type-cast to fix that, either:

```
dmUserSecurity := TdmUserSecurity(TdmUserSecurity.OpenDM(...));
```

Or:

```
dmUserSecurity := TdmUserSecurity.OpenDM(...) as TdmUserSecurity;
```

BTW, why does `OpenDM()` have a `dm` parameter at all? It is useless in the code you showed.  You should either:

1. pass it by `var` and get rid of `Result`

   ```
   unit dmi_Generic;
   ...
   type
     TdmiGeneric = class;
     TDMGenericClass = class of TdmiGeneric;

     TdmiGeneric = class(TDataModule)
     private
       ...
     public
       ...
       class procedure CloseDM(FormName: string; var dm: TdmiGeneric);
       class procedure OpenDM(FormName: string; const dmClass: TDMGenericClass; var dm: TDMGeneric);
     end;
   ...
   class procedure TdmiGeneric.OpenDM(FormName: string;  const dmClass: TDMGenericClass; var dm: TdmiGeneric);
   var
     ...
   begin
     ...
     if dm = nil then
       dm := dmClass.Create(nil);
     with dm do
       ...
   end;

   class procedure TdmiGeneric.CloseDM(FormName: string; var dm: TdmiGeneric);
   begin
     FreeAndNil(dm);
   end;
   ```

   ```
   uses
     UserSecurityDM;
   ...
   procedure TfmMain.actUserManagerExecute(Sender: TObject);
   begin
     TdmUserSecurity.OpenDM(Self.Name, TdmUserSecurity, TdmiGeneric(dmUserSecurity));
     //some code
     TdmUserSecurity.CloseDM(Self.Name, TdmiGeneric(dmUserSecurity));
   end;
   ```
2. get rid of `dm` as a parameter and declare it as a local variable instead:

   ```
   unit dmi_Generic;
   ...
   type
     TdmiGeneric = class;
     TDMGenericClass = class of TdmiGeneric;

     TdmiGeneric = class(TDataModule)
     private
       ...
     public
       ...
       class procedure CloseDM(FormName: string; var dm: TDMGeneric);
       class function OpenDM(FormName: string; const dmClass: TDMGenericClass): TDMGeneric;
     end;
   ...
   class function TdmiGeneric.OpenDM(FormName: string; const dmClass: TDMGenericClass): TdmiGeneric;
   var
     dm: TDMGeneric;
     ...
   begin
     ...
     dm := dmClass.Create(nil);
     with dm do
       ...
     Result := dm;
   end;

   class procedure TdmiGeneric.CloseDM(FormName: string; var dm: TDMGeneric);
   begin
     FreeAndNil(dm);
   end;
   ```

   ```
   uses
     UserSecurityDM;
   ...
   procedure TfmMain.actUserManagerExecute(Sender: TObject);
   begin
     dmUserSecurity := TdmUserSecurity.OpenDM(Self.Name, TdmUserSecurity) as TdmUserSecurity;
     //some code
     TdmUserSecurity.CloseDM(Self.Name, TdmiGeneric(dmUserSecurity));
   end;
   ```

Either way, since you are calling `OpenDM()` on the `TdmUserSecurity` class and not on the `TdmGeneric` class, you might consider using the `Self` class type inside of `OpenDM()`, then you can remove the `dmClass` parameter:

```
unit dmi_Generic;
...
type
  TdmiGeneric = class;
  TDMGenericClass = class of TdmiGeneric;

  TdmiGeneric = class(TDataModule)
  private
    ...
  public
    ...
    class procedure OpenDM(FormName: string; var dm: TdmiGeneric);
  end;
...
class procedure TdmiGeneric.OpenDM(FormName: string; var dm: TdmiGeneric);
var
  ...
begin
  ...
  if dm = nil then
  begin
    if Self = TdmiGeneric then
      raise Exception.Create('Must call OpenDM() on a descendant class type').
    dm := TDMGenericClass(Self).Create(nil);
  end;
  with dm do
    ...
end;
```

```
uses
  UserSecurityDM;
...
procedure TfmMain.actUserManagerExecute(Sender: TObject);
begin
  TdmUserSecurity.OpenDM(Self.Name, TdmiGeneric(dmUserSecurity));
  ...
end;
```

Or:

```
unit dmi_Generic;
...
type
  TdmiGeneric = class;
  TDMGenericClass = class of TdmiGeneric;

  TdmiGeneric = class(TDataModule)
  private
    ...
  public
    ...
    class function OpenDM(FormName: string): TDMGeneric;
  end;
...
class function TdmiGeneric.OpenDM(FormName: string): TdmiGeneric;
var
  dm: TDMGeneric;
  ...
begin
  ...
  if Self = TdmiGeneric then
    raise Exception.Create('Must call OpenDM() on a descendant class type').
  dm := TDMGenericClass(Self).Create(nil);
  with dm do
      ...
  Result := dm;
end;
```

```
uses
  UserSecurityDM;
...
procedure TfmMain.actUserManagerExecute(Sender: TObject);
begin
  dmUserSecurity := TdmUserSecurity.OpenDM(Self.Name) as TdmUserSecurity;
  ...
end;
```

Comment: I lean towards `Self` class type, but compiler says 'This form of method call only allowed for class methods' on `if Self.ClassType = TdmiGeneric then`.

Comment: My bad, should be `if Self = TdmiGeneric ` instead.